# Where to find "Serif" font from Ubuntu to be installed and used on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, fonts

I've been using TeXworks 0.4.5 r1280 in Windows 7 and TeXworks 0.5 r952 in Ubuntu 12.04. I like the font on Ubuntu much more than on Windows. It is easier to read and to work with. On Ubuntu this font is called "Serif" in the TeXworks settings:

[image: font dialog in Ubuntu]

On Windows, it doesn't exist:

[image: font dialog in Windows]

Where can I find this font in some format that I will be able to install and use on Windows 7? Could it be font embedded into TeXworks or it is a system-wide font?

**Update:** As suggested by Ignacio, I've used Character Map and found out that this is a DejaVu Serif font, which can be found in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf`. I've copied this file to the Windows machine, opened it with Windows Font Viewer and installed it. After restarting TeXworks it appeared on the list of fonts as `DejaVu Serif`. To further improve the appearance of the font, I've adjusted the screen resolution value to match my monitor (setting found in the Preview tab in Preferences dialog):

[image: screen resolution setting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up Character Map in Ubuntu, select "Serif" from the font pulldown, and right-click-hold on a character in the Latin-1 character set ("Basic Latin"). The font name will appear at the bottom of the window that pops up.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me to figure out the font name: DejaVu Serif. I copied and installed all TTF files from the /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/ and selected it in TeXworks settings. I have also adapted the DPI value in the settings of the TeXworks to match my monitor. The text is so much more appealing to read now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there's no such thing as *the* serif font. I'd guess [its liberation serif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts), or [deja vu serif](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page). You *are* very likely to find the font you're looking for in `/usr/share/fonts/` presumably in the 'truetype' directory.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I have tried `LibrationSerif-Regular.ttf`, `DejaVuSerif.ttf` and `FreeSerif.ttf`. None of them is the font that I am looking for. Also these fonts are available in the TeXworks settings as separate entries in the dropdown list.

Comment: http://tug.org/fonts/ this is a pretty comprehensive list of fonts used with TeX - on further research, it might be a tfm, not a ttf file . Unfortunately without looking through all of them, and comparing them to your serif font, its pretty hard to work out which one it is

Comment: It turned out to be DejaVuSerif.ttf after all. I think the issue was that I was comparing different texts and of different size.